# What SQL func to use instead of UNION to have only one condition?

Tags: sql, join, union

I need to make this SQL request shorter. Shall I use JOIN?
Everything is the same between UNION's, but table names.

UPD: Is it possible to use only one set of conditions to all the tables?

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE
(condition1)
AND
(condition2)

GROUP BY column1, column2, column3

UNION

...                                              (N times)

UNION

SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_N WHERE
(condition1)
AND
(condition2)

GROUP BY column1, column2, column3

ORDER BY column1, column2, column3;
```

Comment: It totally depends on tables and queries.

Comment: @AlexanderI . . . I think you have a problem with your data model.  It seems to me like all the data should be stored in a single table.  That would simplify your query.  In addition, I sincerely doubt you want `union`, because that removes duplicates, which seems unlikely when working with counts.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's not disputable as it's data model of the framework I study to work in. 
Thank you! UNION ALL much better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query can be written as:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(*)
FROM ((SELECT column1, column2, column3, 1 as which
       FROM TABLE_1
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT column1, column2, column3, 2 as which
       FROM TABLE_2
      ) UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) t
WHERE (condition1) AND
      (condition2)
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, which;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in multiple tables like that you need at some point to select from all of the tables, creating a long query like that. You could create a view which does the union of all the tables, then you can select from the view as it were one object. Something like

```
CREATE VIEW all_tables as 
SELECT column1, column2, column3, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_1 WHERE
(condition1)
AND
(condition2)
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
UNION
...
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.
Yes it is stored in many tables and the set of conditions is the same. Is it possible to make it one to all the tables? I thought of using JOIN, but I'm afraid the request will be too complex.

Comment: Joins would give you different set of data meaning you could get column1,column2, column3, counfromTbl1, countFromTbl2, countFromTbl3 etc.  But you still need to join them using SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between a `JOIN` and a `UNION` is that if you use a join your columns won't be all in one, you will have different columns for each table and also the data would have to match in a certain column in each table which I am guessing is not what you want because of the use of a union.

bjorsig did suggest a `VIEW` approach where you wouldn't have to explicitly give all the tables each time you want to get this data but that wouldn't work if your `N` value is different each time.

I would suggest a [dynamic SQL approach](https://www.sqlshack.com/dynamic-sql-in-sql-server/).

Here is a quick sample of what you could try, however this does assume your table names do follow the convention of `table_1`, `table_2` etc.

This is in SQL Server but should be easy to apply in other technologies.

```
DECLARE @total_iterations INT = 2;

DECLARE @Select_Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT column1, 
                                                column2, 
                                                column3, 
                                                COUNT(*) ';
DECLARE @Condition NVARCHAR(MAX) = ' WHERE (condition1)
                                       AND (condition2)
                                       GROUP BY column1, column2, column3';

DECLARE @Full_Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @counter INT = 1;                                 
WHILE @counter <= @total_iterations
BEGIN
   SET @Full_Query = (SELECT(@Full_Query + @Select_Query + 'FROM table_' + CAST(@counter AS NVARCHAR)  + @Condition))
   IF(@counter < @total_iterations) BEGIN
        SET @Full_Query = (SELECT(@Full_Query + ' UNION '))
   END;
   SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END;
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Final_Query;
```

This creates and runs this query.

```
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   table_1 
WHERE  ( condition1 ) 
       AND ( condition2 ) 
GROUP  BY column1, 
          column2, 
          column3 
UNION 
SELECT column1, 
       column2, 
       column3, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   table_2 
WHERE  ( condition1 ) 
       AND ( condition2 ) 
GROUP  BY column1, 
          column2, 
          column3
```

Comment: Thanks!
Actually `N` is const, but for me being new to SQL it's a useful sample.